# Error compiling release build with Realm (DexArchiveMergerException)

Tags: android, realm

I keep getting this error even with multiDexEnabled and have been looking around forums but can't seem to find the same issue. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
Error:Program type already present: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\232, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\0.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\1.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\2.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\3.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\4.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\6.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\7.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\8.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\10.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\12.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\13.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\14.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\20.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\21.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\22.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\23.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\24.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\25.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\26.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\27.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\28.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\29.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\30.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\32.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\33.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\34.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\35.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\36.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\37.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\38.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\39.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\40.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\41.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\42.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\43.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\44.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\45.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\47.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\48.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\49.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\50.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\51.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\52.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\53.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\54.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\55.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\56.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\57.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\58.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\59.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\60.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\61.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\62.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\63.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\64.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\65.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\66.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\67.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\68.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\69.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\70.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\71.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\72.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\73.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\74.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\76.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\80.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\81.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\82.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\83.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\84.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\85.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\86.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\87.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\88.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\89.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\90.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\91.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\94.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\95.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\97.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\98.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\99.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\100.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\101.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\102.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\103.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\104.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\106.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\107.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\108.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\109.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\110.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\111.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\112.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\113.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\114.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\115.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\116.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\117.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\118.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\119.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\120.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\121.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\122.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\123.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\124.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\125.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\126.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\127.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\128.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\129.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\130.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\131.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\132.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\133.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\134.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\135.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\136.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\137.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\138.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\139.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\140.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\141.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\142.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\143.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\144.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\145.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\146.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\147.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\148.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\150.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\151.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\152.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\153.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\154.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\155.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\156.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\157.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\158.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\159.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\160.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\161.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\162.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\163.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\164.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\165.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\166.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\167.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\168.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\169.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\170.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\171.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\172.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\173.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\174.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\185.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\186.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\187.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\188.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\189.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\190.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\191.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\192.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\193.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\195.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\217.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\218.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\224.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\225.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\226.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\227.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\228.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\229.jar, D:\Android Projects\mobile-hub\Hub Configurator\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\release\231.jar
```

I'm currently using Realm in an Android Library that I compile from another project's APK, as well as this current project with the gradle configs listed below.

**Project Gradle**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha09'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.3"
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs '../sharedLibs'
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Mobile app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "co.igloohome.app"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.0.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation project(':libs')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Shared Library between mobile and things app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'


android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'


defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.1"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

//Rx for android
api 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0'
api 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
// Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
// explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
api 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
// Retrofit & OkHttp
api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
//Android NTP Library for TimeManagementService
api 'com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library-extension-rx:3.3'

//internal SDK
api (name:'<Release-version-of-Another-Library>', ext:'aar')

//SQL Cipher
api 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.6'

//Multidex
api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}
```

**Things app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "co.igloohome.igloohub"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 27
    versionName "1.0.20"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "so"
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
api 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:+'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation project(':libs')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.beust:klaxon:0.30'
implementation 'com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.instacart.truetime-android:library-extension-rx:3.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android{
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'
}
}
```

I apologise for the poor indentation, I'm not familiar with how to indent whole blocks of code.

Comment: The shared library should use a `@RealmModule` to define its RealmObject classes.

Answer (score 1):

Your library needs to expose its classes using a `@RealmModule` with `library = true`, otherwise both the app and the library code will generate the file you see a conflict reported on

Something like:

```
// Library
@RealmModule(allClasses = true, library = true) 
public class MyLibraryModule() { }


// App
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .modules(new MyLibraryModule(), Realm.getDefaultModule())
  .build();
```

You can read more her:https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#schemas